# Passing data between viewControllers in swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, segue

I was wondering if their were ways to send data to another view as soon as one view loads. I'm trying to make an app that stores something like a highScore but the only way to pass the data from the gameOver view to the mainMenu is if they click main menu and using the prepareForSegue method. Is their a way I could send it in like the viewDidLoad function?

Thanks!

Comment: show what you have done here.

Comment: Dato' Mohammad Nurdin do u mean code?

Comment: @DavosSnow Yep, you shouldn't ask a "how to do" question without showing what you've attempted to do youself. See: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

**According you use an `UINavigationController`, `GameOverViewController`**

On your main menu add this code :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
    let gameOverVC = navigationController.topViewController as GameOverViewController
    gameOverVC.highScore = 26
}
```

If you don't use an `UINavigationController` :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let gameOverVC = segue.destinationViewController as GameOverViewController
        gameOverVC.highScore = 26
    }
```

Then, add your highScore var : `var highScore: NSString!` like this :

```
class GameOverViewController: UIViewController {

    var highScore: NSString!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        println(self.highScore)
    }
}
```

It should works.

If not, please add more code in your post.

**EDIT :**

By this way, you will just pass data forward, not backward. To pass backward use `Delegation`, `Singleton`, `NSNotificationCenter` or `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score 0):

To **pass data backward side**, i.e. from second view to first, there are option like `Delegation` Pattern and `NSNotificationCenter`.

Suppose we using **NSNotificationCenter**.

In your case, We need to Send `highScore` to `MainMenu` from `GameOver` Class.

1. Register your notification.(in viewDidLoad of MainMenu Class)

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateHighScoreFromGameOver:", name: "notificationUpdateHighScoreFromGameOver", object: nil)
   ```
2. Create method to handle posted notification. (in MainMenu Class)

   ```
   @objc func updateHighScoreFromGameOver(notification: NSNotification){
   ```

   NSNumber highScore = notification.object;

   ```
       }
   ```
3. Post Notification When your game is Over(next line after displaying game over message).

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notificationUpdateHighScoreFromGameOver", object: hightScore_ofTypeNSNumber)
   ```
4. Remove observer once you are done. (in viewWillAppear of MainMenu Class)

   ```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self name: "notificationUpdateHighScoreFromGameOver", object: nil);

   //alternatively you can remove all observers on this object:
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);
   ```

**Note :** If you will not remove previous added observer and add it again, the method will be called two times. If you add same observer third time, the method will be called three times, and so on.